# How to setup allure-report in nightwatch?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js, allure

I am pretty new to allure-report. Can someone share the setup and configuration part of allure-report in nightwatch ?.

[image]

global module

````
const path = require('path');
const cwd = process.cwd();

module.exports = {
    reporter: function(results , done) {
      let srcResult = path.join(cwd,'/reports/client','*.xml');
      console.log('path to the reports'+srcResult);
      var generation = allure(["generate", "--clean", srcResult]);
      generation.on ('exit',()=>{
        done();
      });
    }
};

path to the reportsC:\uiautomation\reports\client\*.xml
C:\uiautomation\reports\client\CHROME_80.0.3987.122_Windows_user_registration.xml is not a directory
Report successfully generated to allure-report```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use `allure-commandline` for this.

try this:

- run `npm install allure-commandline --save-dev`
- create external global.js with following code:

```js
var allure = require("allure-commandline");

module.exports = {
    reporter: function(results , done) {
      let srcResult = "../path/to/your/xml/result";
      var generation = allure(["generate", "--clean", srcResult]);
      generation.on ('exit',()=>{
        done();
      });
    }
};
```

after this, you should be able to find **allure result** folder , and to open them u can use `allure open` command. also please remember to configure your **globals_path** in your nightwatch conf file.

Comment: I tried this and it is generating the allure-results directory. when i run `allure serve` it is opening the report but nothing is displaying in the report. please find the attached image. i opened in the Firefox as well. same results. please find the attached scree-shot in the question.

Comment: i cannot find your screenshot. however, if you already have the report generated using `allure generate` , you should use `allure open <directory to allure-report>` to open it instead of `allure serve`.

Comment: I tried with just `allure generate` and 'allure open'. Its same results i am getting. I've attached the image file in the main question.

Comment: The only 2 reasons i can think of given ur screenshot. 

[i]. your path to the nightwatch generated XML report is incorrect when running `allure generate <path-to-xml-report>` , please double check if it's pointing correctly.

[ii] the nightwatch xml reports are stored in nested directories (eq. test_outputs/test1/mytest.xml), you can try to put the wildcard at to ensure it grab everything under the tests_output directory eq. `allure generate tests_output/*` ,
lemme know if this helps.

Comment: I tried exactly the way you have in the global module. As you mentioned , I believe my path to the xml report is not correct. I am getting the an exception when i use  wildcard. please check the main post for more info. i cannot post in the comments.

Comment: try to use `let srcResult = path.join ( "path" , "to" , "your" , "xml" , "*" );` , note that the last one is wildcard. and `console.log (srcResult);` to ensure it's indeed pointing to the root directory of nightwatch xml report

Comment: I've tried this time with the correct path and console.log shows the correct path to the report but however it returns the specified path is not a directory. I still have the same problem which i showed in the screen-shot earlier. I also see that report didn't generate allure_result folder before creates the html report. Do i need `nightwatch-allure-adapter` module or `allure-commandline` is enough to create the html report ? Please find in the main post for the latest.

Comment: your console log path should be this `C:\uiautomation\reports\client\*` do not include the .xml extension ( try: `let srcResult = path.join(cwd,'/reports/client','*');`

Comment: @HendryAng allure report counts Suite name as a test case. Suppose I have a suite, "Testing", and inside which I wrote 2 test cases, "test1" and "test2". Now, after execution, the Allure report shows the test case count as 1, which is "Testing".  It should show 2 test cases (1 and 2). What to do?